# foreach loop with custom class list not printing correct value

Tags: c#

I have a foreach loop that i'm trying to iterate through a list attached to a class

```
public class FInfo
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string MD5Hash { get; set; }   
}
```

it's small class right now but i may add to it later.

However i'm not sure how to access it

```
private void DirOut(string sDir)
    {

        try
        {
            string[] array1 = Directory.GetDirectories(sDir);
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < array1.Length; i1++)
            {
                string d = array1[i1];
                dirC++;

                outliststring.Add(new FInfo {FilePath = d, MD5Hash = "N/A"});

                try
                {

                    String md5string; 
                    String[] array = Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                    {
                       string f = array[i];


                       outliststring.Add(new FInfo { FilePath = f, MD5Hash = "N/A" });

                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception excpt)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
                }
                DirOut(d);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);

        }

}
```

This code adds the items to the list.

then I've using this code to write it to a text file.

```
 Stream fileStream2 = sfd.OpenFile();
        using (StreamWriter sw =new StreamWriter(fileStream2))
        {
            foreach (FInfo fp in outliststring)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":- " + fp);


            }

            sw.Close();
            fileStream2.Close();

        }
```

However this just write the time and date then FInfo. Can someone explain how i add both the values to the sw.writeline command.

Thanks

Comment: @mjwills it prints a line in the text file with the current date and time and where `fp` should be the filepath and then a hash number (not implemented yet) it just has Finfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like:

```
foreach (FInfo fp in outliststring)
{
  sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":- " + fp.FilePath +" "+ fp.MD5Hash );
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's so simple i should have known

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the best approach would be to override `ToString()` in `FInfo`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{FilePath}\t{MD5Hash}";
}
```

The method `WriteLine` automatically calls `ToString()` on your `fp` object to combine it with the rest of the string for the output.  Right now your code is just using the `ToString()` defined on a base class (most likely `object`) whose default behavior is just to print the name of the class, as you've observed.

An alternative approach is to just use the properties directly:

```
sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":- " + $"{fp.FilePath}\t{fp.MD5Hash}" );
```

Comment: Why is this a better approach than accessing the class properties? I'm genuinely curious because it looks like a bit overkill to me, but it has to be a good reason since several people answered the same.

Comment: Nitpicky criticisms: Technically `fp.FilePath` and `fp.MD5Hash` aren't fields but properties ;).
Also I'd would make more sense to wrap the whole `sw.Writeline` parameter in a interpolated string and not mix and match concatenation with it

Comment: @ikerbera the override Method is in certain cases better, like if you want to print the same thing over and over so instead of doing `sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":- " + $"{fp.FilePath}\t{fp.MD5Hash}" );` you can just do `sw.WriteLine(fp);` which is a lot more concise. But for one offs I recommend using string interpolation

Comment: @ikerbera -- It's always a good idea to override `ToString()` since you never know where it's going to be used/needed.  It's better to control the string your code supplies when something calls that method, because it gets called a lot in places you wouldn't necessarily expect.  For example, in the debugger, when you're looking at the variable it will print the results of `ToString()`.  This is helpful when you have a collection of things and want to be able to quickly see which is which.

Comment: And doing that doesn't preclude using the other approach I outlined.

Comment: @rory.ap Yep, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `ToString` method in your `FInfo` class:

```
public class FInfo
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string MD5Hash { get; set; }   
    public override string ToString() => $"FilePath:{FilePath}, MD5Hash:{MD5Hash}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# there are multiple places where the `ToString` Method of a object is called where the programmer didn't explicitly have to say so. In your case on the line `sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":- " + fp);` the `fp.ToString();` is called. You can now either do as @rory.ap said override the `ToString` method or use string interpolation like so:

```
sw.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}:- {fp.FilePath}\t{fp.MD5Hash}");
```

**Edit:** String interpolation is a really neat feature in C#, you tell the compiler that it's a interpolated string by placing a `$` before the quotation marks, and then within in the string you can use `{` and `}` (curly braces) to put code into that return or are a string
This is a really powerful feature and replaces now outdated methods like string concatenation (what you're using with the `+`s) and `string.Format()` method